# Rendering to a FBO corrupts another FBO

Tags: qt, opengl

I am using Qt to build an application that renders point clouds. My point cloud is rendered in a `QQuickFrameBufferObject` (A Qt object that wraps an OpenGL frame buffer object and display the result directly on screen).

I also have another frame buffer object (`QOpenGLFrameBufferObject`) that I use to do offscreen rendering that is half the size of the first one.

I am rendering to both from the same function (called `render`).

If I render only in the big FBO, there are no problem, everything looks as it should.

But when I render to both, the content of the big FBO gets corrupted at random (the points are rendered at the right place but are all black). It does not happen on all the frames, but when it happens, all the points are black (on all the VBOs). Which frame gets dark is random.

My VBO contains 3 attributes : `vec3 position`, `float intensity` and `float time`. When the points are black, it seems that my first vertex attribute (`vec3 position`) goes through, but all the other attributes are not set and my colors which depends on these attributes are black (since the attributes are equals to 0);

The vertex shader :

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in float intensity; // randomly equals to 0
layout (location = 2) in float time;

uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix;

flat out vec4 f_color;

vec4 getIntensityColor() {
    return vec4(vec3(intensity / 65535.0), 1.0);
}

void main() {   
    gl_PointSize = properties.pointSize;
    gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);


    f_color = getIntensityColor();
}
```

My render function looks like this :

```
void render() {

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
    glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);

    // the big FBO is bound before the call to this function. Hence why I do not bind it here
    if(_manager.renderToBigFbo()) { 

        glClearColor(_properties.clearColor.redF(), _properties.clearColor.greenF(), _properties.clearColor.blueF(), _properties.clearColor.alphaF());

        glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        QMatrix4x4 viewProjectionMatrix = _properties.camera.viewProjectionMatrix();

        _renderer->beforeRendering(viewProjectionMatrix, _properties, boundingBox, datasetMetadata);
        _renderer->bindVao();

        for(auto const& vbo : _vbos) {
            _renderer->render(vbo.second->data.get());
        }

        _renderer->afterRendering();
        _renderer->unbindVao();

    }

    if(_manager.renderToSmallFbo()) {
        static constexpr int boxSize = 20.0 * _fboFactor + 1; // box of NxNxN.
        QSize fboSize = _size * _fboFactor;

        _smallFbo->bind(); // FBO is bound here

        glViewport(0, 0, fboSize.width(), fboSize.height());

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
        glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        glScissor(_manager.getMousePosition().x() * _fboFactor - (boxSize / 2.0), 
            _manager.getMousePosition().y() * _fboFactor - (boxSize / 2.0), boxSize, boxSize);

        QMatrix4x4 viewProjectionMatrix = _properties.camera.viewProjectionMatrix();

        // change some properties. Will cause the vertex shader to be recompiled
        auto colorMode = _properties.colorMode;
        auto pointSize = _properties.pointSize;
        _properties.colorMode = ColorModeItem::ColorMode::INDEX;
        _properties.pointSize = pointSize / 2;


        _renderer->beforeRendering(viewProjectionMatrix, _properties, boundingBox, datasetMetadata);
        _renderer->bindVao();

        for(auto const& vbo : _vbos) {
            _renderer->render(vbo.second->data.get());
        }

        _renderer->afterRendering();
        _renderer->unbindVao();

        }

        // reset the old color mode
        _properties.colorMode = colorMode;
        _properties.pointSize = pointSize;

        glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

        // do stuff with the FBO's content
        QImage img (_smallFbo->toImage(false));
        QImage image(img.constBits(), img.width(), img.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);

        _smallFbo->release();           
    }

    // needed by Qt
    if(_window != nullptr) {
        _window->resetOpenGLState();
    }
}
```

The `render` member function of the vbos objects bind the buffer, set the vertex attrib pointers and calls `glDrawArrays`.

I am rendering the exact same VBOs and binding the exact same VAOs in both FBOs but the vertex shader is recompiled between the two renders to display a different color set.

The problem disappears if I do not bind the VAO in the small FBO render section (of course, the small FBO no longer contains what I want, but it stops corrupting the other FBO). This is weird since the VAO has been successfully bound in the big FBO section moments earlier.

I have absolutely no idea what can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was re-compiling the shader program while it was still bound and in use. Hence the problem. I refactored the shader compilation step and the problem disappeared